# MySQL Find Repeat Buyers of Specific Products

Tags: sql, mysql

This is a slightly more complicated reporting problem than I usually have. I want to find how many times customers have repurchased individual product listings. (Say, some products have really high sales, but we want to know how much are from first-time purchases and how much are repurchases.)

```
items_purchased:
+----------+------------+----------+
| buyer_id | listing_id | quantity |
+----------+------------+----------+
|     1234 |       5678 |        1 |
|     1234 |       3456 |        1 |
|     9012 |       3456 |        2 |
|     7901 |       5678 |        1 |
|     1234 |       5678 |        1 |
+----------+------------+----------+
```

From that data, I can see listing `5678` has been purchased 3 times but repurchased once. Listing `3456` has been purchased twice but never repurchased. I want to build a report like:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| listing_id | purchases | repurchases | repurchase_rate |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
|       5678 |      1364 |         152 | 11%             |
|       3456 |       892 |         289 | 32%             |
|       3284 |        51 |          30 | 59%             |
|       8763 |         8 |           0 | 0%              |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I think I need a `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` somewhere, definitely a `SUM` I'm guessing, but I'm stumped how to do it. (The "repurchase_rate" I know how to do.)

Comment: How does buying mor than two times affect the repurchase rate? For example, if the same buyer purchases the same item 3 times does it count two times on repurchases or only once for however many repurchases from the same buyer?

Comment: @TharinduPerera, I suppose I unconsciously threw that in as a curveball. I suppose for my client's needs (my wife in this instance) I'm interested in purchases AFTER the initial purchase, so "quantity" column shouldn't matter. But possibly might want to know "how many of a single item has a single buyer purchased over time?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
select *, 1.0 * repurchases / purchases as repurchase_rate
from (
  select listing_id, sum(cnt) as purchases, sum(cnt - 1) as repurchases
  from (
    select listing_id, buyer_id, count(*) as cnt
    from items_purchased
    group by listing_id, buyer_id
  ) x
  group by listing_id
) y
```

Result:

```
 listing_id  purchases  repurchases  repurchase_rate        
 ----------- ---------- ------------ ---------------------- 
 5678        3          1            0.33333
 3456        2          0            0.00000
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZZfWwzYn).

Comment: Love that this was fairly easy to understand without an explainer. I can easily understand and reuse this solution on different but related problems. +1 for the db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could build a CTE that summarizes the count of purchases of a particular `listing_id` by `buyer_id`, subtracting 1 from each to include *only* repurchases:

```
WITH repurchases AS
(
    SELECT
        listing_id,
        SUM(repurchases) AS repurchases
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            listing_id,
            buyer_id,
            COUNT(1) - 1 AS repurchases
        FROM
            items_purchased
        GROUP BY
            listing_id,
            buyer_id
    ) repurchases_by_buyer
    GROUP BY
        listing_id
)
SELECT
    items_purchased.listing_id,
    COUNT(1) AS purchases,
    (SELECT repurchases FROM repurchases WHERE repurchases.listing_id = items_purchased.listing_id) AS repurchases
FROM
    items_purchased
GROUP BY
    items_purchased.listing_id
```

<sup>[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/drwy5YgNPaZSM9mqpLgqEA/2)</sup>

This is probably not the most computationally efficient way to do this considering the somewhat gratuitous use of subqueries, but I'm confident there's room for it to be optimized further to accommodate scaled usage.

Comment: Oh wow, I've never used/seen `WITH` before. From your usage I'm guessing it acts as a stand-in for a subquery? It's difficult to intuit what all it's doing. Care to add a little explainer so we can make this a reusable solution? Also, I think the reuse of the term 'repurchases' is also mudding the waters a bit, possible you could change up those names for clarity? Thank you for the quick reply, I was AFK for the holiday weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count()` and `count() - count(distinct)` to count purchases and repurchases, respectively.

```
SELECT listing_id, COUNT(buyer_id) purchases, 
COUNT(buyer_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT buyer_id) repurchases,
CONCAT(ROUND(100 * (1 - COUNT(DISTINCT buyer_id)/COUNT(buyer_id))), '%')  repurchase_rate
FROM items_purchased 
GROUP BY listing_id;
```

| listing_id | purchases | repurchases | repurchase_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3456 | 2 | 0 | 0% |
| 5678 | 3 | 1 | 33% |

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i9Bp1uPdQXHAJr8ZyjTAch/0)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Fantastic. I didn't realize there was a DB Fiddle, but I guess I should have known there's a fiddle for everything.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT
  p.listing_id,
  COUNT(p.listing_id) AS purchases,
  COUNT(r.listing_id) AS repurchases,
  ROUND((COUNT(r.listing_id) / COUNT(p.listing_id)) * 100, 2) AS repurchase_rate
FROM
  (SELECT listing_id, buyer_id, MIN(quantity) AS first_purchase
   FROM items_purchased
   GROUP BY listing_id, buyer_id) AS first_purchases
LEFT JOIN items_purchased AS p
  ON first_purchases.listing_id = p.listing_id
LEFT JOIN items_purchased AS r
  ON first_purchases.listing_id = r.listing_id
  AND first_purchases.buyer_id = r.buyer_id
  AND r.quantity > first_purchases.first_purchase
GROUP BY p.listing_id;
```

This query does the following:

- Subquery `first_purchases` identifies the first purchase for each `buyer_id` and `listing_id`
- The main query then LEFT JOINs the `items_purchased` table twice: once to count all purchases (`p`) and once to count repurchases (`r`)
- The `repurchases`  count is filtered to only include purchases where the `quantity` is greater than the `first_purchase` quantity
- Finally, it calculates the `repurchase_rate` and formats the output

Please note that the above query assumes that a repurchase is defined as any subsequent purchase where the quantity is greater than the first purchase quantity. Adjust the logic as needed for your specific definition of a repurchase.